# Why does an extra await cause synchronous execution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, .net-4.6.1

I am trying to understand a comment made on a legacy piece of code...

The original code:

```
    public async Task Send(Notification notification)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(notification.Methods.Select(async topic =>
        {
            var client = GetTopicInstance(topic);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
            await client.SendAsync(message); // COMMENT HERE
        }));
    }
```

The comment made was this:

> Return here instead of using await and change the lambda expression to not
> have the async modifier. This will truly ensure you are running the
> SendAsync calls in parallel. Right now, due to the await, it will block
> at every iteration and every SendAsync will be completed sequentially.

So the revised code looks like this:

```
    public async Task Send(Notification notification)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(notification.Methods.Select(topic =>
        {
            var client = GetTopicInstance(topic);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
            return client.SendAsync(message);
        }));
    }
```

What I don't understand is why the second `await` would cause blocking.

My understanding is that the `WhenAll` creates a `Task` for each iteration returned by the `Select`. The original code would appear (to me) to then create another `Task` within each of those `Task`s. I am unclear why those child `Task`s would cause blocking.

Comment: The comment is wrong; they are both equivalent as long as an exception is not thrown.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Many exceptions won't even result in different behavior, although you're right that some would.  Exceptions in the synchronous code would result in different behavior, and multiple exceptions in the `Task` from `SendAsync` would result in different behavior.

Comment: "Right now, due to the await, it will block at every iteration and every SendAsync will be completed sequentially" -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/m2ekKS -> the parallelism is the same regardless of the `await` call because of how the query is evaluated

Comment: Take a look at this blog post by Stephen Cleary, if you haven't already read it: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)